# String tokenizer filter like Shingle in Elasticsearch

Tags: string, elasticsearch, text, nlp, tokenize

I am working on a shopping ecom website where requirement comes to generate meaningful string tokens from product name for auto complete feature. for eg:

**If product name is: "Red Beryl Striped Cotton Shirt"**

then meaning full token can be **"Red Shirt",** "Cotton Shirt", "Striped Cotton Shirt" and "Beryl Shirt".

I had tried generating tokens through **"Shingle" filters** of elasticsearch but not able to produce "Red Shirt" token because term "Red" and "Shirt" are not continues in product name.

Any help would be greateful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you know about `search_as_you_type` types in [elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html)?

Comment: Yes Nate, I am using `Suggester` instead of `search_as_you_type`. All working well there, but my problem here is generating meaningful token from product title. Like i mentioned, 
If product tile is `Red Beryl Striped Cotton Shirt` then `Shingle` filter only generating tokens for siblings words, not for `Red` + `Shirt` together.
Thanks for your reply. Any suggestion would be welcomed. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is `slop` in a [`match_phrase` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html). Though for that example query you'll need a slop of 3, which might be expensive.

Generally, I think you'll want a [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with should clauses on:

- Each token in your search input.
- A phrase search on the full search input (maybe with a slop).

For autocompletion `search_as_you_type` would make most sense as Nate mentions but for that example it wouldn't autocomplete to "Red Shirt".

Comment: Yes, Right Xeraa. I am currently using `Suggester` of elasticsearch for autocomplete and it's working well there. The only problem here is generating tokens which has some meaningful text and that token would be stored in `complete` field of my elasticsearch index. BTW Thanks for your reply. Any other suggestion welcome. :)